# Sincronização de threads em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, python-2.7, sincronização

Estou fazendo um programa que deverá simular a sincronização de arquivos entre duas threads, porém, não conheço muito a linguagem python. Eu já criei as threads, os métodos de lock e os arquivos. Porém não consigo fazer o run selecionar um arquivo na origem, usar lock_read na origem e lock_write no destino.

Alguém sabe como fazer? Eu já tentei de várias formas..

```
import sys, time
from threading import Semaphore, Thread
from pprint import pprint
from random import random, choice
from time import sleep



class RWLock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_rdcnt = Semaphore(1)
        self.r = Semaphore(1)
        self.w = Semaphore(1)
        self.readcount = 0


    def lock_read(self):

        self.w.aquire()
        self.m_rdcnt.acquire()
        readcount+=1
        if (readcount == 1):
            self.r.acquire()
        self.m_rdcnt.release()
        self.m_rdcnt.acquire()


    def unlock_read(self):
        readcount-=1
        if (readcount==0):
            self.r.release()
        self.m_rdcnt.release()
        self.w.release()


    def lock_write(self):
        self.r.acquire()
        self.w.acquire()


    def unlock_write(self):
        self.r.release()
        self.w.release()


class Arquivos:
    def __init__(self, nome, tamanho):
        self.nome = nome
        self.tamanho = tamanho
        self.status = RWLock() 

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s tamanho %d" % (self.nome, self.tamanho)
    def __repr__(self): return self.__str__()


jekyll = []
jekyll.append(Arquivos("abc",10))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('dfg', 4))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('hij', 5))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('plo', 6))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('aad', 12))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('aes', 7))
jekyll.append(Arquivos('qas', 5))

hyde = []
hyde.append(Arquivos("abc",10))
hyde.append(Arquivos('dfg', 4))
hyde.append(Arquivos('hij', 5))
hyde.append(Arquivos('plo', 6))
hyde.append(Arquivos('aad', 12))
hyde.append(Arquivos('aes', 7))
hyde.append(Arquivos('qas', 5))



class SingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, origem, destino):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.origem = origem
        self.destino = destino

    def run(self):
        l=RWLock()
        while 1:
            #print('Bloqueando para Leitura %s' % (l))
            l.lock_read()
            #print('Desbloqueando para Leitura %s' % (l))
            l.unlock_read()
            #print('Bloqueando para Escrita %s' % (l))
            l.lock_write()
            #print('Desbloqueando para Escrita %s' % (l))
            l.unlock_write()




t1 = SingThread(jekyll, hyde)
t2 = SingThread(hyde, jekyll)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```